# Dynamically resizing grid cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, responsive-design

I am attempting to create a two-row, three-column grid layout:

[image: grid]

This is pretty simple. I am wondering how to expand any one of the given cells, causing the other cells to rearrange around the expanded cell:

[image]

I am not looking for a pure-CSS solution necessarily. I have it working, but I am hardcoding absolute positions based on what cell I am expanding, which feels dirty :/ Thanks!

Comment: Is the expanded square always in the top left? Or does it depend on the position of the square before it was expanded (top right expand would make the big square be in the top right)? If it depends on the latter, what happens when a middle square is expanded?

Comment: Good question: the position depends on which cell was expanded. If a middle cell is expanded, I can just pick left or right, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bin-packing solution like a treemap.  You can sort the rectangles and create a tree and split the tree along the 2 axis. Pick the next item and put it in the best free space. Then restart the process. There is a jquery treemap plugin. Here is an example but packing lightmaps. It's a pseudo-code:http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/.

Comment: Thank you for the term "tree map" in this scenario. I will look into this now.

Answer (score -1):

If you're always going to have a 3x2 grid, I don't see the harm in hard-coding parts of it.

Here's a solution that uses CSS, and just shifts the tiles around a bit if they are either the middle or last tile in the row.
http://jsfiddle.net/m2pWL/1/
You can just click the squares to make them bigger.

Note that the #wrapper needs to have a width of this formula

```
(3 * [width of small square]) + 6
```

This is because of the borders takes up 1 pixel as well.